# copy to clipboard current path from console with no mouse

Tags: command-line, bash, clipboard

I'm wondering if it possible to copy to clipboard output of `pwd` command.

I often need to copy some path and I have to select it with mouse, do several clicks and that is annoying for me.

What I want is piping output of `pwd` command to something that will copy it to clipboard so I do not have to touch my mouse

Edit: it will be great if it is possible with some built-in

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can use a program called `xclip`. For installing it type:

```
sudo apt-get install xclip
```

and then do

`pwd | xclip` -- which copies output of pwd to xclip

Now to get the output type:

`xclip -o`

or to copy to the "standard" clipboard (to avoid having to use `xclip -o`)

`pwd | xclip -selection clipboard`

for more options use

`man xclip`

Comment: how can I `cd` after that? `xclip -o | cd` do not work

Comment: you can do it by `cd xclip-o` but use the `` to close the xclip -o..whatever code is inside `` in the terminal will post the output of that code.it will get the output of xclip -o and then cd will change directory to it

Comment: @micgeronimo you could use one of either [`xclip -o | xargs cd`](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-bsd-xargs-construct-argument-lists-utility/) or `cd $(xclip -o)`

Comment: I suggest using `cd "\`xclip -o\`"` if there are spaces in cwd...

Comment: This doesn't work :/ if I look at a file `cat banana.txt | xclip` it copies fine. `pwd | xclip` doesn't copy anything.

Answer (score 10):

You can use xclip or xsel, to install xsel just do:

```
sudo apt-get install xsel
```

and then do

```
pwd | xsel -b
```

to copy the output of pwd to the clipboard.

To get the content of the clipboard you can use:

```
xsel -b
```

Here you can read a review of xclip and xsel:

http://trembits.blogspot.com/2009/09/clipboard-from-command-line-xclip.html

Comment: `xsel` works perfectly. `xclip` didn't work for me.