# How to copy the stdout of a command to the clipboard in a default Ubuntu installation?

Tags: clipboard, stdout

I ran up against [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/597788/copy-to-clipboard-current-path-from-console-with-no-mouse) question, and i found it quite interesting.

While researching for that, i found out that a solution had been posted already [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/184397/how-do-i-pipe-terminal-standard-output-stdout-to-the-clipboard) on `AskUbuntu`, plus multiple times on `StackOverflow` and on `Unix & Linux`, but all the solutions provided involved the use of `xclip` or `xsel`, which are not available in a default `Ubuntu` installation (i.e. they're not present in a Live DVD, for example).

Question: How to copy the stdout of a command to the clipboard in a default Ubuntu installation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Copy stdout to the clipboard without installing additional software

Although it seemed impossible to me at first (and it is a bit of a detour), it *is* very well possible without additional software. The only thing needed is `python`, like it is installed from a fresh install.

This solution uses `python`'s ability to copy text to the clipboard, and make it available to other applications, as explained (a.o.) [here](http://www.answermysearches.com/python-how-to-copy-and-paste-to-the-clipboard-in-linux/286/).

#### The construction

- The first step is to create an empty textfile, let's say `terminal_log.txt`
- The command(s) that run in the terminal are followed by `| tee /path/to/terminal_log.txt`, e.g.

  ```
  pwd | tee /path/to/terminal_log.txt
  ```

  The output will be in the terminal, as well as written to `terminal_log.txt`
- Meanwhile, a script (see below) runs in the background, detecting changes to the file
- If the file is changed, the change will be copied to the clipboard

The result of the example above:

```
pwd | tee /path/to/terminal_log.txt
```

If I open `gedit` and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>

```
/home/jacob/Desktop
```

#### How to setup

1. create an empty (log-) file, `terminal_log.txt`
2. Copy the script below into an empty file. In the head section, set the path to `terminal_log.txt`, save it as `read_output.py`
3. Start the script with the command

   ```
   python /path/to/read_output.py
   ```
4. Run in (another) terminal your command, followed by:

   | tee /path/to/terminal_log.txt
5. The output of your command is copied to the clipboard

If you use it frequently, you could run it as a startup application.

#### The script

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pygtk
pygtk.require('2.0')
import gtk
import time

#--- enter the path to the log file below
f = "/path/to/terminal_log.txt"
#---

output1 = open(f).read().strip()

while True:
    time.sleep(1)
    output2 = open(f).read().strip()
    if output1 != output2:
        tx = output2.replace(output1, "")
        clipboard = gtk.clipboard_get()
        clipboard.set_text(tx)
        clipboard.store()
    output1 = output2
```

---

#### Additional information

```
command | tee /path/to/terminal_log.txt
```

Will not copy `stderr` to the clipboard. To copy both `stdout` and `stderr` to the clipboard, use:

```
command > >(tee /path/to/terminal_log.txt) 2> >(tee /path/to/terminal_log.txt >&2)
```

as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/692407/1391444)

Comment: Nice answer, and +1 for using `Python`! Thanks!

Comment: It was actually a surprise to me as well :)